# "ARTShape" was not found in the UIManager - React Native

Tags: react-native

[image: Please find the below image for reference]

Im using React native Expo(36.0.0).
I am developing dashboard screen for my project. So, I just want to show some pie charts in dashboard screen. I have tried many libraries for all kind of charts. Nothing worked for me. Finally I have used react-native-pie with the help of youtube video. Still it is showing me the same error.

And I am new to React native.

Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import Pie from 'react-native-pie';

class HomeScreen extends Component
{
constructor(props)
{
  super(props);
}
render()
{
return(
  <ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.homeContainer}>
      <View style={{paddingVertical:15, flexDirection:'row', width:350, justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <Pie
          radius={80}
          sections={[
            {
              percentage:10,
              color:'red'
            },
            {
              percentage:30,
              color:'green'
            },
            {
              percentage:60,
              color:'orange'
            }
          ]}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
)
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   homeContainer:
   {
     alignItems:'center',
     justifyContent:'center'
   },
})

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: Can you add the error as text, so it's searchable?

Answer (score 6):

I think, this is not added in RN 0.62 with auto linking feature, so you can do it like this:

go to your ios folder and your project and click on podfile and add the below line with the other similar pods or add it to the end of the podfile.

```
  pod 'ReactNativeART', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/art'
```

after that go to your editor terminal open your project from the root folder and then:

```
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 5):

## Fix for Android

#### Step 1

Add this lines to android/settings.gradle

```
include ':react-native-art'
project(':react-native-art').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/art/android')
```

#### Step 2

Add this lines to android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation project(':react-native-art')
}
```

#### Step 3

Add this lines to android/app/src/main/.../MainApplication.java

```
import com.reactnativecommunity.art.ARTPackage;

...

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      
      ...
      
      packages.add(new ARTPackage());
      
      ...
      
      return packages;
    }
```

- reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/art

Thx for help unknown asian guy https://bocoder.tistory.com/m/40

Comment: Thanks to asian guy, and thanks to you for reposting!

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install @react-native-community/art --save
```

Comment: Please do not post link only answers

Comment: Isn't @Sabaoon Bedar more elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

run the code below.

```
~$ npm install @react-native-community/art --save
```

**For react-native < 0.60** you need to **link** ReactNative ART:

```
~$ react-native link @react-native-community/art
```

**For react-native >= 0.60** ReactNativeART should be **autolinked** and no additional action is required.